# I am using django right now and i don't know how i could parse the data direct from the admin panel to the homepage template

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates

I did this in my `views.py` file

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from . import models

def home(request):
    context = {
        'name': models.alldets,
    }
    return render(request, 'sites/home.html', context=context)
```

on my `home.html` i did this

```
<h1> {{ name }}</h1
```

and this is now my `models.py`

```
from django.db import models

class alldets(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

all files are in the same directory. I want to parse the data in my models.py to my homepage through the admin panel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to display all `alldets` on your homepage, change context definition in your `views.py` to:

```py
    context = {
        'alldets': models.alldets.objects.all(),
    }
```

and `home.html` template to:

```html
{% for item in alldets %}
<h1> {{ item.name }}</h1>
{% endfor %}
```